# Number of threads that are executing omp task

Tags: c++, openmp

For the code below, if list_file.size() is 12, i.e. we have more threads than the number of iteration in for loop, what can we say about the number of threads that are running each task block? Would only 1 thread is running each task block, or more than 1 threads will be running each task block?

```
omp_set_num_threads(24);
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int m = 0; m < list_file.size(); m++)
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **without running omp_get_num_threads**? So "how do I get the number of threads without getting the number of threads?"

Comment: What is a _task block_?

Answer (score 1):

Each task region will be executed by one thread.  OpenMP will not use more threads to execute a single task.  Thus, if your outer parallel loop only generates 12 tasks, then you can only keep a maximum of 12 threads busy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

My follow up question is this, once a thread starts working on a task, the thread will keep working on the task until the task is finished, is this correct? In such case, if we don't have any data sharing among the threads, there is no need to use lock within each task?

Comment: Once a task is executing on a task, the thread will run the task to completion. However, the currently executing task may be interrupted by other tasks at so called "task scheduling points" (TSC). An example of a TSC is the `#pragma omp task` contruct, where the encountering thread may suspend it's current task to execute the newly created one. Unless the `untied` keyword is used, the interrupted task will always resume executing on the task where it started to execute.

Comment: Hi, I've added an image of the problem I'm stuck with to my original post, hope that you can help to take a look and give me some insight. 
In each task, 2 private vectors called vector_words and hash_table will be created, the thread will read a text file, add all the words in the file to the vector_words, after that it will map each word into the hash_table, and since only thread is executing the task there is no data race and thus no need to use any lock. However, when I remove the lock from the code the output becomes incorrect. I'm not sure why this is the case.